# Python definition returning "set" when it should be returning dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

Just trying my best to learn some Python.  Building a script that will take some arguments and generate a dictionary to be used later in the script.  Having some issues with the object returned on this definition:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from argparse import ArgumentParser

def argument_analysis():
    """
    This will take in the arguments, and turn them into a filter dictionary
    -n --name       This will pinpoint a single host via hostname Tag
    :return:filter_dictionary
    """
    parser_options = ArgumentParser()
    parser_options.add_argument("-n", "--name", dest='name', type=str, help="Filter by hostname.")
    arguments = vars(parser_options.parse_args())

    name_filter = arguments['name']
    filter_dictionary = {}
    if name_filter:
        filter_dictionary = {"tag:Name", name_filter}
        return filter_dictionary
    elif len(filter_dictionary) < 1: return "No arguments."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = argument_analysis()
    print args
```

The problem is when I run it (with applicable options):

```
$./test.py -n foo
set(['foo', 'tag:Name'])
```

But I'm expecting this output:

```
{'tag:Name', 'foo'}
```

I can't seem to locate why I'm getting a 'set' returned instead of the dictionary I created?  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, instead of:

```
filter_dictionary = {"tag:Name", name_filter}
```

which is `set` literal syntax, you want:

```
filter_dictionary = {"tag:Name": name_filter}
                             # ^ note colon, not comma
```

which is `dict` literal syntax.

Comment: OMG thank you so much.  Was beating my head against the keyboard all morning.  I am ashamed I missed that.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`{"tag:Name", name_filter}` denotes a *set* literal.  You need to replace the comma with a colon if you want a dictionary literal:

```
filter_dictionary = {"tag:Name" : name_filter}
```

See below:

```
>>> type({1, 'a'})
<class 'set'>
>>> type({1 : 'a'})
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [literals in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

Comment: OMG thank you so much.  Was beating my head against the keyboard all morning.  I am ashamed I missed that.  Thanks for your time.